# script not working in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML file that is loaded by Angular JS in `ng-view`. This file contens code:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="searchbox.tpl.html">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
</script>
```

Why input fiels is not displayed in template? I see blank page.

This is Angular JS code:

```
$scope.searchbox = { template: 'searchbox.tpl.html', events: events };
```

Updated:

HTML file with include:

```
<div class="input-wrap">
     <div ng-include="searchbox.template"></div>
 </div>
```

HTML file `searchbox.template`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.address" ng-trim="true" ng-minlength="3" required>
```

Comment: where are you binding `searchbox.template` in your HTML?

Comment: rename you html file to `searchbox.tpl.html` from `searchbox.template`

Answer (score 0):

You have added `script` that doesn't mean that it will render inner html on the page. After reading that script from Html, Since the type of script is `type="text/ng-template"` so `angular` internally put that `script` content inside a [**`$templateCache`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) service, And you can access that as template by using its `id` value as url in anywhere.

For getting shown it on the page you should use `ng-include` that will have `src` with `searchbox.tpl.html`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-include="searchbox.template"></div>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkCrvi5Nfoch8RzIr0Wg?p=preview)

Comment: Need or not to specify full path for `searchbox.tpl.html` in line: `type="text/ng-template" id="searchbox.tpl.html"`?

Comment: you could directly specify the path like `ng-include="'searchbox.tpl.html'"` but currently you have it in a scope so it would be `ng-include="searchbox.template"`

Comment: could you look at plunker

Comment: I looked, when I use your solution in my plunker it does not work

Comment: could you reprodoce the problem here in plunkr plwae